# Naming scheme for typedefs

Tags: c, posix, naming, typedef

I'm working on a library that extensively used constructs like

```
typedef struct foo_bar_s {
    ...
} foo_bar_t;
```

It's a bad idea to use the _t suffix, because it's a POSIX reserved namespace. The _s suffix for structs is also pretty useless. So I thought I can change it all to

```
typedef struct foo_bar {
    ...
} foo_bar;
```

or if the struct name is not needed

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} foo_bar;
```

However, I cannot distinguish typedefs from regular symbols (variables, etc.) anymore. Is this really such a big deal and should I use a different suitable naming scheme for the typedefs? Or does it not matter that much?

I'm really not so sure. What do you think? Also, what recommendations do you have for typedef naming schemes?

Answer (score 8):

Although, "_t" is reserved, it is very unlikely that you will encounter a problem. However, this convention is a remnant of older versions of C where this syntax was required in order to name structs, and so nowadays you can simply write something like the following (omitting the typedef and the typedef names):

```
struct name_of_struct
{
   type1 member1;
   type2 member2;
   // ...
   typeN memberN;
};
```

And yes, you can use single line comments ("//...") in the current standard of C.

Comment: _t is indeed reserved by POSIX

Comment: Now that two people said it. I double-checked, and it turns out you are right. I'm going to fix that.

Comment: _t is not reserved by POSIX in the sense that nobody else is allowed to use such names.  Rather POSIX implementations may only use types names of this form.

Comment: Actually, please see:
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

According to the document:
"Names that end with ‘_t’ are reserved for additional type names. "

Of course, if one always prefixes one's function and type names with the name of their library (e.g. "mylibrary_suchandsuchtype_t"), it is very unlikely that they will have a conflict with future versions of the C standard library.

Answer (score 5):

I use the naming conventions used in Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/): a type is named with the module name and a capital T.  So for example, the type of sequences is `Seq_T`, and the type of hash tables is `Table_T`.  Within the implementation of a module Hanson uses `#define` to abbreviate just to `T`.  This is basically [Modula-3](http://www.modula3.org/) conventions applied to C programming, but I find that after a brief initial shock it works well.