# What does this line of C do?

Tags: c

I was just reading about a library called [sofia-sip](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/) and this line appeared in a [code sample](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/refdocs/msg/index.html#msg_parsing_memory):

```
msg_iovec_t iovec[2] = {{ 0 }};
```

For reference, here is the definition of [msg_iovec_t](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/refdocs/su/structsu__iovec__s.html):

```
struct iovec {
    void *iov_base;     // Pointer to data.
    size_t iov_len;     // Length of data.
};
```

Comment: Highly off-topic, but isn't the "_t" suffix reserved for POSIX types and its highly discouraged to attach it to your own type names?

Comment: @JustSid – [Yes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02) and [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186072/naming-scheme-for-typedefs/1186143#1186143).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This creates an array of two `iovec` structures on the stack and initializes **all** members of both array elements to zero.

The initializer `{{ 0 }}` only gives an explicit value for the first member of the first array element: `iovec[0].iov_base`. The supplied value 0 is converted implicitly to a null pointer.

The other members of the first array element and the other array elements are also initialized, implicitly: pointers to null and arithmetic types to 0.

The line can be written equivalently as

```
msg_iovec_t iovec[2] = { 0 };
```

This is the shortest standard way to zero-initialize an entire object, so it is idiomatic. Some compilers might accept an empty initializer list `{}` as an extension. Some compilers might issue a warning for this form and require enough braces to designate the first non-aggregate member (two pairs as in the original line).

The effect is similar to

```
msg_iovec_t iovec[2];
bzero(iovec, sizeof iovec);
```

except cleaner and portable, because a pointer filled with zero bytes is not necessarily a null pointer.

Comment: +1, the point here being that everything is zeroed out, not just the iov_base field of the first element.

Comment: A reason for having a zero inside, is that historically not all compilers have agreed on what is "sufficient".

Comment: Also `bzero(&myptr, sizeof(myptr));` isn't the same as `myptr = 0;` (`myptr = NULL;`).

Comment: @aaz: `{}` is **not valid C**. It's C++ only. `{0}` is the shortest universal zero initializer in C.

Comment: Thanks. @Bo, @R. – you're right, the grammar demands a non-empty list (though `gcc` accepts it without `-pedantic`). @Conrad – that's what I meant by "similar" – clarified.

Comment: The reason you see the double braces in the code is that GCC authors managed to damage the support of universal zero initializer idiom `{ 0 }` by issuing warnings when it is used to initialize multi-level aggregates (like an array of structs). Normally one'd use just `{ 0 }`, but because of the warnings one has to use `{{ 0 }}`.

Comment: @AndreyT – That explains the original line, thanks. I think the best way to deal with those warnings is the same as for the "suggest parentheses around `&&`" ones – with `-Wno-missing-braces`.

Answer (score 2):

First bracket declares that array is being initialized. The second declares that structure's `iovec` first field: `iov_base` is being initialized by NULL value