# Getting the type specifier given an object

Tags: c++, templates, stl, types

I am trying to write a template function that will take an STL container and will display all the occurrences of the elements in it and the number that they have occurred. I am planning to use a map, iterate through the container and either add a new element if it does not exist or increment the count of occurrences for the element.

Declaration:

```
template < typename Container_t >
void findOccurrences (const Container_t& inContainer);
```

My question is: can I somehow get the type specifier of the element that the container holds? 
So when I create my map the key value would be the element in the `inContainer`. 
Something like :

```
map < typeid ( * inContainer.begin()), int > occurrences;
```

Or would I have to change my template to something like this:

```
template < typename Container_t , typename Element_t >
void findOccurrences ( const Container_t & inContainer , Element_t dummy )
{
  map < Element_t , int > occurrences;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter>
void histogram(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T;

  std::map<T, size_t> h;

  while (begin != end) ++h[*begin++];

  // now h holds the count of each distinct element
}
```

*Usage:*

```
std::vector<std::string> v = get_strings();
histogram(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: `iterator_traits` also requires C++0x, does it not?

Comment: @Ben: Err... Nope, iterator_traits aren't new to C++0x

Comment: @Ben: No, `iterator_traits` has always been there

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Yay for genericity! Should I have said `const Iter end`, though? @Ben: You can't use iterators without [iterator traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/)!

Answer (score 3):

You want `typename Container_t::element_type`

That is,

```
std::map <typename Container_t::element_type, int>
```

Comment: Names ending in `_t` are reserved.

Comment: @Ben: I don't know if that's entirely true in any scope... but then it's not that relevant to this question. Thanks for the info anyway :)

Comment: @Ben: I've never seen anything in the Standard about reserving those names.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186072/naming-scheme-for-typedefs/1186143#1186143

Comment: @Ben: It's about global scope, ain't it? In this situation it is not a problem at all

Comment: @Armen: That's probably true, although a future library update could potentially define a macro by that name, breaking things.

Comment: @Ben: I don't think that a name ending with _t is a suitable name for a macro )

Answer (score 1):

With C++0x, it's really easy:

```
map<decltype(*c.begin()), int> occurrences;
```

With C++03, you probably need to use a typedef from the container:

```
template<typename Container>
// ...
map<Container::element_type, int> occurrences;
```

Comment: It's `decltype`, not `declspec`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Right you are!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at "RTTI" (run-time type information)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information

I hope this helps.