# Name custom LinkedList type

Tags: c++, design-patterns, typedef, naming

This is a question of Best practices.

I have implemented a LinkeList (https://github.com/ivanseidel/LinkedList) and it works fine.

The thing is, I'm writing a code that is repeatedly having things like: `LinkedList<Beat>`, which in my case, is a `Rithm`, but Rithm is not a type, class or anything, it's just how I see it.

I want a way of simplifying that name, without creating an extended class of `LinkedList` or anything. Just some way of replacing it.

I have tried with `typedef`:

`typedef LinkedList<Beat> Rithm;`

And also with a define (NAHH... I don't like it either)

`#define Rithm LinkedList<Beat>`

Is there a "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: Rhythm. The `typedef` is preferred.

Comment: Don't use macros when you have better tools. Here I would go with the `typedef`. There are some special cases where `typedef` can not be used but those are rare.

Comment: How can I use it? Just like I wrote there @pasztorpisti

Comment: @IvanSeidel `typedef LinkedList<Beat> Rithm;` is perfect, now you can write `Rithm` instead of `LinkedList<Beat>`.

Comment: E.g. instead of `SomeFunc(LinkedList<Beat> rithm)` you can write `typedef LinkedList<Beat> Rithm` and then `SomeFunc(Rithm rithm)`.

Comment: Great! It worked just great! Thanks... Speared me some useless classes

Comment: Best Practices:  use standard library data structures before rolling your own.  Next, search for a library containing the data structures before rolling your own.  After exhaustive search or unique customization, roll your own.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMatthews , I did that library with Arduino being it's target, and also the users (that are mostly dumb witch C++).. Before doing it, I did a deep search for a "simple" library, but couldn't find any good one with repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[typedef wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) also says the same:

> The purpose of typedef is to form complex types from more-basic machine types[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) and assign simpler names to such combinations. They are most often used when a standard declaration is cumbersome, potentially confusing, or likely to vary from one implementation to another.

One should give some thought to [naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186072/naming-scheme-for-typedefs) the typedef as well.

> I use the naming conventions used in Dave Hanson's C Interfaces and Implementations: a type is named with the module name and a capital T. So for example, the type of sequences is Seq_T, and the type of hash tables is Table_T.