# Standard alternative to POSIX typedef

Tags: c, posix, typedef

Before I read that POSIX reserved the typedefs ending in `_t` I used it frequently. What would be a good commonly-used standard alternative for this suffix?

Comment: I think that's up to you, as long as you make it a standard in your code.

Comment: If I were you, I just wouldn't use a postfix >o<

Comment: There's no definitive right or wrong. The only thing that is *more* right is to be consistent.

Comment: `_type`. Anyways, it's really up to you and therefore opinion-based. What matters is consistency.

Comment: I understand that you need to be consistent with your naming conventions, but I was wondering if there is a *standard* for it.

Comment: As others have said, consistency is key. Also, the _t_t reservation is a convention honored more in the breach than in observance. Just like the fact that all identifiers beginning with strstr are reserved by the C standard library (thus, variable names like streetAddressstreetAddress should not be used). Frankly I see little value in the `_t` suffix. Such type names are used where you would expect to see one of the built in types (i.e. ∫int, float,float, char` etc) and can therefore be nothing other than a typedef or possibly macro, but we ALL use  UPPER_CASE for that , don't we?

Comment: something odd going on in SO - I hit the limit on characters and it started replacing backticked sequences like `_t` with _t_t

Comment: I've experimented with [`_T`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186232/2410359) with some success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Standard" is a big word. If you refer to the ISO C, it's beyond its job to define that; indeed, it does use names like `time_t` or `size_t` because it's allowed to as POSIX is secondary to it. Moreover, this convention does not apply to Windows-based programming environments, for instance.

IMHO, it's not really needed to state that *a type is a type*. C has a limited number of types so it's elementary to determine whether it's a built-in type or an ADT. Also, such built-in types have lower case one word names: if you saw `stat_buffer` you would immediately know it may not be a built-in type.

Whatever choice you make it's important to keep it *consistent* across your source code. Anyways, very frequent choices I see may be:

- Uppercase nomenclature, like `Time` or `Pid`
- `_type` suffix, like `time_type` or `pid_type`
- Invisible suffix, like `time` or `pid`